# I have got this Error while building gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > No slave process to process jobs, aborting

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I have got this Error while building grade

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > No
>   slave process to process jobs, aborting

**Build.gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.colorball.madness"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        } } }dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/PTAdRevMob.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')}
```

Comment: can you please share your build.gradle here?

Comment: please check build.gradle file

Comment: I got same issue sometimes since new android studio (3.0.X), each time I got this one, I need to invalidate cache and restart, and it is working...

Comment: Chol can you please explain

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart works for me you can check it here; https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-no-slave-process-to-process-jobs-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This thread was mentioned in [No slave process to process jobs, aborting android studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618738/no-slave-process-to-process-jobs-aborting-android-studio-3-0-1) and I had exact same issue. (Error was not going in-spite of shrink=false, minify=false, invalidte cache).

Simple solution which solved the issue was close the android studio & relaunch it. Not sure why "invalidate cache & restart" failed. But seems that Android is becoming new MSWindows.. (I lost 1.5 hours in finding on forums & trying to fix the error.. Eventually it turned out to be a windows trick.)

Hope this age old trick will help somebody..

Answer (score 3):

Add `shrinkResources true` in your build.gradle and try to build.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
  }
}
```

Comment: I too started getting this error today. Mine is a library module so can't add shrinkResources

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 
I added  `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` to my build.gradle(Module:app)
and rebuild my project.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

- At first go to these setting in android studio ([first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSWf7.png))
- and check ([second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSbn1.png)) "Use embedded JDK (recommended)"
- and also add shrinkResources true in your build.gradle .

  buildTypes {
              release {
                  shrinkResources true
            }

  ```
  }
  ```

At last rebuild the project.

Comment: Please describe the process on a list of to dos, don't rely on images.

Comment: First got to File>>Other Settings>>Default Project Structure...       On that window please check the option Use Embedded JDK (recommended)

Comment: And also add buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
  }
}          in your app level build.gradle file if necessary