# No slave process to process jobs, aborting android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

I am getting this error while generating signed apk :

```
Error:Execution failed for task app:processReleaseResources No slave process to process jobs
```

I already tried minifyEnabled false,shrinkResources false in build.gradle file.

I already tried invalidate cahces and restart, rebuild.